# javascript how to get order of object after sorted by its property

Tags: javascript, sorting

```
let o = {
    a: {value: 3},
    b: {value: 1}, 
    c: {value: 4}, 
    d: {value: 2}
};
```

we know c>a>d>b, so the output shoule be

```
{
    a: {value: 3, order: 2},
    b: {value: 1, order: 4}, 
    c: {value: 4, order: 1}, 
    d: {value: 2, order: 3}
}
```

How to achieve that in js?

Comment: You can't order object properties in JavaScript. Even if you build an object with presorted properties it's not guaranteed they will be displayed in the same order.

Comment: @VladimirBogomolov I mean get the order/rank according to value property in each sub-object

Comment: Then you code something like this :
`const order = Object.keys(o).sort(function(a,b){ return o[b]['value']-o[a]['value']})`

Comment: What, if some object share the same value like `{a: {value: 3}, b:{value: 1}, c:{value:1}`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could get the keys sort them with the object's values and assign the order to the given keys.

```js
let o = { a: { value: 3 }, b: { value: 1 }, c: { value: 4 }, d: { value: 2 } };

Object
    .keys(o)
    .sort((a, b) => o[b].value - o[a].value)
    .forEach((k, i) => o[k].order = i + 1);

console.log(o);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Very elegant, I like this.

Comment: I did a performance test to determine the best alternative: You won!
https://codepen.io/HerrSerker/pen/drbedJ?editors=0011

Comment: You won in Chrome and Firefox, but lost in Edge. No Safari here!

Answer (score 2):

You could sort the values in your object, and then loop over your object keys to check if the current value is the same as the current one from the `sorted` array, if it is, you can set the current object `order` property to the index+1 (as the index starts at 0):

See example below:

```js
const o = {
    a: {value: 3},
    b: {value: 1}, 
    c: {value: 4}, 
    d: {value: 2}
},

sorted = Object.values(o).sort(({value:a},{value:b}) => b-a);

sorted.forEach(({value}, i) => {
  for(key in o) {
    if(o[key].value == value) o[key].order = i+1
  }
});

console.log(o);
```

However, this is not the best solution in terms of time-complexity, and I'm sure can be improved

Answer (score 1):

Combining the answers of [Nina](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54806743/476951) and [Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54806795/476951)

```js
let myObject = { a: {value: 3}, b: {value: 1},  c: {value: 4},  d: {value: 2} };


Object
  .values(myObject)
  .sort(({value:  a}, {value: b}) => b-a)
  .forEach((k, i) => k.order = i+1)

console.log(myObject)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```